# Inbox keeps opening by itself when app is launched by a push notification

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

In the SO iOS app, if the app is launched via a push notification, the app keeps opening the Inbox section.

**Steps to reproduce:**

- launch app via a push notification.
- Inbox opens up. You can optionally view new items in the inbox.
- close the inbox.

**Observed behavior:**

- when you close the inbox, scroll up in the stream, within a few seconds, the inbox opens up again. This keeps repeating after the inbox is closed.

**Expected behavior:**

- the inbox closes and opens only upon tapping the inbox icon in the top right.

App Version: 1.0.1
OS: iOS 8 B3. (Also observed on iOS 7.1.4)
Device: iPhone 5 A1429

Comment: Wait, aren't the push notifications for items in the inbox?  Why wouldn't the notification bring you to the inbox, in that case?

Comment: That behavior works correctly. However, when you close the inbox after interacting with the notification, it opens up again without any user interaction.

Comment: Oops, missed that part.

Comment: [tag:ios-app]: "When posting bug reports, please specify the app's version."

Comment: Updated the OP with the relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done a lot of work and testing in this area but could not reproduce this issue on the latest app version (1.1.0) nor on the beta version.

Please let me know if you are still experiencing it on the latest release.