# Blank screen after opening a notification in iOS8

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In my device (iPhone 6, iOS v8.0.2, app v1.2.0.138) whenever I receive a notification and I tap it in order to open the application, the screen that is displayed is blank.

I need to quit the app, re-open it, go to my 'inbox' and tap the last notification in order to see the question screen, focused on the comment.

This is not new (for me) in v1.2.0.138; it has been happening for at least the last ~7 updates that I've done.

Comment: This started happening to me only after upgrading to iOS 8 (using iPhone 4S) so looks like yet another bug/quirk of that infamous version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug happened specifically if the app wasn't running in the background, but was instead launched from a push notification. This was a highly untested code path, and a bug was introduced a while back which caused the inbox to be displayed twice, causing the app to simply freeze.

If iOS8 is terminating the app more aggressively than earlier versions, it's possible it was making the issue surface more often.

Fixed in **beta version 1.2.0.140**.

Comment: Not sure that's the case, earlier today I opened a push notification while the app was running in the background, and it just caused the app to focus and didn't do anything beyond that. No freeze, but also didn't work as expected.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that sounds like a different kind of issue. Please submit a bug report for that.

Comment: Thanks, will do if persists in new version. :)

Comment: Also, what about [this other bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235339/inbox-keeps-opening-by-itself-when-app-is-launched-by-a-push-notification?rq=1)? Sounds related, so was it also fixed? :)

Comment: OK, confirmed both issues with push notifications (freeze and ignoring) are fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm running 1.2.0 (Oct 31) on my iphone 6 and am frequently hit by this bug.  Any way you can push an update to the app store with these fixes?

Comment: @Aaron we are planning on submitting an update soon, in the next 1-2 weeks hopefully.